# I uploaded html file containing embedded image encoded base64. But google couldn't convert this file

Tags: google-drive-api

As title, I uploaded html file, it contained embedded image encoded by base64. I can correctly see all contents with safari web browser.

I want to convert this html file to Google Document, so I turned on "convert" flag to "YES", in GTLQueryDrive instance.

It seems that conversion is success, but when I try to open converted file, this is just progress control instead of image what should be there. I waited several minutes, but that progress control is never ended.

Also I manually try to convert html file to google document in google docs website using "Export to Google Document", but it didn't work.

Why google can't convert this file to their own format?

Following is html file what I uploaded:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4QBYRX....">
```

Comment: I don't think embedded images are supported. I did a quick test and they simply ignored my embedded image. The only way to upload html with images may be this one, but I did not try:
http://tqcblog.com/2009/01/28/uploading-html-with-images-to-google-docs

Comment: are there any new news about that issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're expecting too much from the API. 
The API deals will upload a single blob of content. As an option (convert=yes) it will open that blob, parse it and convert it to a native Google Doc.

You seem to be expecting the server to realise that there is an embedded content tag, and the server should somehow reach down to the client, find it, and pull it up. That's never going to happen.

The steps you will need to go through are:-
1. Parse the HTML to find any embedded images
2. Upload each image to Drive and store the returned item
3. Grab the url from the item returned in (2)
4. Patch your HTML so the IMG SRC is that in (3)
5. Upload the HTML